# Would $ \lim_{\sigma\rightarrow0^+}\int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma}\frac{1}{\sigma}f(x)dx$ be equal to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Suppose a limit of the form

$$ \lim_{\sigma\rightarrow0^+}\int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma}\frac{1}{\sigma}f(x)dx$$

where $f(x)$ is an integrable function.

I think that this limit would be zero, since we would be taking an integral at a single point, even if the argument was divergent. Is this correct?

Comment: Well, it's quite clearly $2$ for $f=1_{[-1,1]}$, so it's certainly not always zero.

Comment: "an integral at a single point, even if the argument was divergent. Is this correct?"  No,  Consider the $\delta$ function counter-example.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I was only considering functions, not distributions, but indeed the delta function would work. Anyways, f(x)=1 is a sufficiently easy example to prove my statement wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Apply fundamental theorem of calculus and show that the desired limit is $2L$ provided $L=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the $1/\sigma$ is just a constant and can move outside the integral this is essentially just half the average value of the function on small intervals centered at the origin.

So it can be any value you like.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily.

Consider the case when $f(x)=1$ for $x\in[-1,1]$, and $f(x)=0$ outside the interval.

In general, you may want to take a look at the [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem).

Comment: ...or $\delta(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposition is wrong. This is a counterexample: Consider any integrable function which is constantly 1 on some symmetric non-empty interval around 0. For small enough values of sigma, the integral is exactly 2. Therefore the limit is also 2.

Comment: Right, that was an easy example. I should look for another approach to the original problem I was addressing then. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With $x=y\sigma$ it becomes $\lim_{\sigma\to0^+}\int_{-1}^1f(y\sigma)dy$, which if we can use dominated convergence is$$\int_{-1}^1\lim_{\sigma\to0^+}f(y\sigma)dy=\int_{-1}^1f(0)dy=2f(0)$$for $f$ continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think its also worth noting that the limit you are looking for is given by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem which I will state in the context of the Lebesgue measure on the Euclidean metric space.

Let $f\in L^1$ then for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ it follows that $$\lim_{r\downarrow 0}\frac{1}{|B_r(x)|}\int_{B_r(x)}f(y)dy = f(x).$$